# problems in routing in rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, omniauth

I have added the omniauth and devise gems and was adding facebook login support. This is my routes.rb file:

```
resources :authentications do
  match 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications/#create', :via => :post
end
```

I tried post as well as get in the via part.
Here is the controller for authentications controller.

```
def create
  auth = request.env["rack.auth"]
  current_user.authentications.find_or_create_by_provider_and_uid(auth['provider'], auth['uid'])
  flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
  redirect_to authentications_url
end
```

Here is the rake routes output

rake routes

```
               authentications GET    /authentications(.:format)                     authentications#index
                               POST   /authentications(.:format)                     authentications#create
            new_authentication GET    /authentications/new(.:format)                 authentications#new
           edit_authentication GET    /authentications/:id/edit(.:format)            authentications#edit
                authentication GET    /authentications/:id(.:format)                 authentications#show
                               PUT    /authentications/:id(.:format)                 authentications#update
                               DELETE /authentications/:id(.:format)                 authentications#destroy
                   conferences GET    /conferences(.:format)                         conferences#index
                               POST   /conferences(.:format)                         conferences#create
                new_conference GET    /conferences/new(.:format)                     conferences#new
               edit_conference GET    /conferences/:id/edit(.:format)                conferences#edit
                    conference GET    /conferences/:id(.:format)                     conferences#show
                               PUT    /conferences/:id(.:format)                     conferences#update
                               DELETE /conferences/:id(.:format)                     conferences#destroy
                      profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)                            profiles#index
                               POST   /profiles(.:format)                            profiles#create
                   new_profile GET    /profiles/new(.:format)                        profiles#new
                  edit_profile GET    /profiles/:id/edit(.:format)                   profiles#edit
                       profile GET    /profiles/:id(.:format)                        profiles#show
                               PUT    /profiles/:id(.:format)                        profiles#update
                               DELETE /profiles/:id(.:format)                        profiles#destroy
                               GET    /conferences(.:format)                         conferences#index
                               POST   /conferences(.:format)                         conferences#create
                               GET    /conferences/new(.:format)                     conferences#new
                               GET    /conferences/:id/edit(.:format)                conferences#edit
                               GET    /conferences/:id(.:format)                     conferences#show
                               PUT    /conferences/:id(.:format)                     conferences#update
                               DELETE /conferences/:id(.:format)                     conferences#destroy
 activity_bigbluebutton_server GET    /bigbluebutton/servers/:id/activity(.:format)  bigbluebutton/servers#activity
    rooms_bigbluebutton_server GET    /bigbluebutton/servers/:id/rooms(.:format)     bigbluebutton/servers#rooms
         bigbluebutton_servers GET    /bigbluebutton/servers(.:format)               bigbluebutton/servers#index
                               POST   /bigbluebutton/servers(.:format)               bigbluebutton/servers#create
      new_bigbluebutton_server GET    /bigbluebutton/servers/new(.:format)           bigbluebutton/servers#new
     edit_bigbluebutton_server GET    /bigbluebutton/servers/:id/edit(.:format)      bigbluebutton/servers#edit
          bigbluebutton_server GET    /bigbluebutton/servers/:id(.:format)           bigbluebutton/servers#show
                               PUT    /bigbluebutton/servers/:id(.:format)           bigbluebutton/servers#update
                               DELETE /bigbluebutton/servers/:id(.:format)           bigbluebutton/servers#destroy
  external_bigbluebutton_rooms GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms/external(.:format)        bigbluebutton/rooms#external
                               POST   /bigbluebutton/rooms/external(.:format)        bigbluebutton/rooms#external_auth
       join_bigbluebutton_room GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id/join(.:format)        bigbluebutton/rooms#join
    running_bigbluebutton_room GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id/running(.:format)     bigbluebutton/rooms#running
        end_bigbluebutton_room GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id/end(.:format)         bigbluebutton/rooms#end
     invite_bigbluebutton_room GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id/invite(.:format)      bigbluebutton/rooms#invite
join_mobile_bigbluebutton_room GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id/join_mobile(.:format) bigbluebutton/rooms#join_mobile
                               POST   /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id/join(.:format)        bigbluebutton/rooms#auth
           bigbluebutton_rooms GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms(.:format)                 bigbluebutton/rooms#index
                               POST   /bigbluebutton/rooms(.:format)                 bigbluebutton/rooms#create
        new_bigbluebutton_room GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms/new(.:format)             bigbluebutton/rooms#new
       edit_bigbluebutton_room GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id/edit(.:format)        bigbluebutton/rooms#edit
            bigbluebutton_room GET    /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id(.:format)             bigbluebutton/rooms#show
                               PUT    /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id(.:format)             bigbluebutton/rooms#update
                               DELETE /bigbluebutton/rooms/:id(.:format)             bigbluebutton/rooms#destroy
                                      /auth/:provider/callback(.:format)             authentications/#create
                          root        /                                              profiles#new
              new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#new
                  user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                       devise/sessions#create
          destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                      devise/sessions#destroy
                 user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#create
             new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                  devise/passwords#new
            edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)                 devise/passwords#edit
                               PUT    /users/password(.:format)                      devise/passwords#update
      cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                        devise/registrations#cancel
             user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#create
         new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                       devise/registrations#new
        edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                          devise/registrations#edit
                               PUT    /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#update
                               DELETE /users(.:format)                               devise/registrations#destroy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
match 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications/#create', :via => :post
```

Should be

```
match 'auth/:provider/callback' => 'authentications#create', :via => :post
```

Where `authentications` is controller & `create` is method